# MySQL: Select * columns that contains 1 but missing 2

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table.
In the table i have "serie" and "number".
It looks like this:

```
id    serie    number
-------------------------------
0       1           1
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       2           1
4       2           2
5       2           3
6       3           1
7       3           3
```

Maby you noticed that "serie" 3, doesnt have the number 2.
Now i´d like to do a query where i search for series containing, let´s say number 1, but not number 2.
Ho can i do this?

I started like this:

```
SELECT serie FROM table as ser1 WHERE number = "1";
SELECT serie FROM table WHERE number = ser1.number AND number != "2";
```

Comment: can you give sample data and provide the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `not exists` like that:

```
SELECT serie 
FROM table as ser1 
WHERE number = "1" and not exists 
(select 1 from table where serie = ser1.serie and number = "2");
```

Comment: Thank you. This answear was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping with a proper `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT serie    
FROM mytable
GROUP BY serie
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN number = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN number = 2 THEN 1 END) = 0
```